# Create a matrix of 1 and zeros to mask out Rayleigh-Tyndall lines in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am doing fluorescence spectroscopy and process the files afterwards with R. I would like to create a matrix of 1 and 0 such that I can mask out the Rayleigh-Tyndall lines from the excitation-emission-matrices (EEM).

The EEMs have 44 columns (excitations) and 602 rows (emissions). The excitation wavelengths range from 240 to 455 nm in 5 nm steps. The emission wavelengths range from 300 to 600.5 in 0.5 nm steps. The resulting matrix to mask out should look something like this (This is just a small cut out of the mask out matrix. The actual matrix is 44*602 in size):

```
    240 245 250 ... 300 305 310 ... 455
300   1   1   1 ...   0   1   1 ...   1
300.5 1   1   1 ...   1   1   1 ...   1
...
305   1   1   1 ...   1   0   1 ...   1
...
310   1   1   1 ...   1   1   0 ...   1
...
480   0   1   1 ... 
...  
600   1   1   1 ...   0   1   1 ...
600.5 ...
```

When the mask out matrix (the one desired) is created I want to multiply it with the actual EEM values. Something like this should then do the trick:

```
corrected_EEM_Intensity <- Mask.Matrix * Sample_EEM
```

The EEMs look like this (44 columns * 602 rows in size):

```
        240  245 ... 455
300   202.7  ...
300.5 190.5  ... 
...   ....   ...
600    82.4  ...
600.5  45.9  ...
```

So I would like to divide the excitations through the emissions and vice verse. In case the emission is a factor of the excitaton and vice versa there should be a 0 in the matrix. In other cases there should be a 1.

To make things more complicated I would like to do it not just for the corresponding factors but within a range of 10 nm. This means that for example excitation 430 divided by emission 440, and excitation divided by 450 should also give a 0.

The real mask out matrix should then look something like this (meant as short example):

```
    240  ... 400 ... 455
300   1
300.5 1  ...   1 ...   1
...   1    1   1   1   1
...
390   1    1   0   1   1
...   1    1   0   1   1
400   1    1   0   1   1
...
600
600.5 1    1   1   1   1
```

How can I do this? After a lot of research and some own trials, I could not find an answer to this.

Comment: Providing some example data (e.g., the EEM matrix) and an example calculation would help to answer your question.

Comment: You say: " If the excitation wavelength (in nm) or a multiple of it equals the emission wavelength (also in nm) or a multiple of it there should be a zero in the matrix.". If I have two numbers `a` and `b` then `a*b` is a multiple of both. So if I follow your definition, your matrix should have zeroes everywhere. Please rephrase.

Comment: As @flodel states, Any pair of numbers shares a least common multiple. If what you intend to test for is pairs where one element is a factor of the other, see my solution below.

Comment: I am sorry for the rather poor and confusing description of my problem. I am re-writing the question in order to improve it. Please see the question again. Any help to the solution of my problem is still greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Strohmi, it's much clearer now. Cheers.

Comment: To be a little more precise (or pedantic ;-)), I'd recommend using "divisor", rather than "factor".  The latter has specific meanings in statistics & R; it is also frequently with specific adjectives in number theory (e.g. "prime factors").  In contrast "divisor" is quite adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to test for pairs where *a* is a factor of *b*, or vice versa, you can use the following (EDIT: this now considers a modulo of <= 10 as being zero, i.e. if *a* is within 10 of a factor of *b*, the corresponding matrix cell is set to zero):

```
cols <- seq(240, 455, 5)
rows <- seq(300, 600.5, 0.5)
# Create a two-column matrix containing all possible excitation-emission pairs.  
d <- expand.grid(rows, cols, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# For each pair, test whether the smaller is a factor of the larger
# Set the number on the right hand side of the comparison (<=) to the 
#  maximum distance (from a true factor) within which numbers will be
#  considered factors.
test <- apply(d, 1, function(x) max(x) %% min(x) <= 10)

# Create a matrix and populate with the (inverse) outcome of the test
res <- matrix(as.numeric(!test), ncol=44, nrow=602,
              dimnames=list(rows, cols))

# Partial output
res[c('300', '300.5', '305', '310', '430', '480'), 
    c('240', '245', '250', '300', '305', '310', '440', '455')]
#      240 245 250 300 305 310 440 455
#300     1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1
#300.5   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1
#305     1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1
#310     1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1
#430     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1
#480     0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: This is about what I want. Now, the problem is extended such that I not only want the corresponding factors to be a 0 but also within a range of 10 or 20 nm. This means that, e.g. excitation 440 divided by emission 430 should also give a zero. I hope I am clear in stating what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `outer()`.

```
excitations <- seq(from = 240, to = 455,   by = 5)
emissions   <- seq(from = 300, to = 600.5, by = 0.5)

names(excitations) <- as.character(excitations)
names(emissions)   <- as.character(emissions)

tol <- 10
mask.fun <- function(x, y) as.numeric(x %% y > tol     &
                                      x %% y < y - tol &
                                      y %% x > tol     &
                                      y %% x < x - tol)

mask.mat <- outer(X = emissions, Y = excitations, FUN = mask.fun)
```